# Using cut into a shell script with variables

Tags: shell, variables, cut

I am using cut to eliminate last two characters of a file:

```
cut -c1-40 <inputfile >outfile
```

Before, I have used wc to know the number of characters in the file:

```
wc -c inputfile
```

Now I would like to use this information to write a shell script
First I have obtained the total of characters in the file and subtracte 3 from that number. I would like to use the content of the variable to use it on cut.

```
nc=`wc -c < $inputfile`

nc=`expr $nc - 3`
```

Now I would like to have something like

`cut -c1-$nc <inputfile >outfile` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sh
head -c-2
```

```
 -c, --bytes=[-]K         print the first K bytes of each file;
                            with the leading `-', print all but the last
                            K bytes of each file
```

Or to delete first two characters

```
tail -c+3
```

```
 -c, --bytes=K            output the last K bytes; alternatively, use -c +K
                          to output bytes starting with the Kth of each file
```